# How can I make each Packed Bubble a different color?

Tags: tableau-api

I have a Packed Bubble dashboard. My Y axis is a list of names and my X axis is a decimal. I want each differing number to be a different color. Can I do this manually?

[image: Dashboard]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to color each bubble with a separate color just use the field that each bubble represent in the color shelf. If I understood your data correctly, each bubble basically represents one campaign, so you should use that as the color.

You can manually assign color using Color>Edit Color and assigning the color of your choice. 
See image 1.[image: Image 1 - color using campaign]

If you want to color your bubbles based on your measure `AVg(NPV/Marketing $)`  you can do as **Alex Blakemore** mentioned and use your measure as a stepped color or gradient.

You can use Color>Edit Color here too , in this case manually assigning color is a bit difficult. But if you play with number of steps, the gradient pre-select, etc, you can usually get very close to what ever your wanted it to look like.

Answer (score 0):

Put your numeric field on the color shelf, and either edit the colors to use a stepped set of colors - or change the field to be discrete and choose individual colors to taste.

Comment: Even changing to discrete I cannot find a way to assign a color to each individual bubble.